# EF 5 foreign key names

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have an entity called `User` and another called `AvailableConsumption`.

There's an association of 0..1 to 1 between them and `AvailableConsumption` is supposed to have a `User`'s FK called `UserId` (which is the name of the `User` table's PK and the name I would like to put to the FK).

What happens is that every time I make changes to the model, it renames `UserId` to `User_UserId` (the FK doesn't appear as property in the model).

Is it possible to avoid this behavior through model only?

PS: I'm using C#' Entity Framework 5 with model first approach.

Comment: Are you using `CodeFirst`? `Model First`?

Comment: You cannot do what you want with model first approach. The only code first approach gives possibilities to control this.

Comment: Both cannot coexist, right? If I try code first to solve this, every time I switch back to model first, I'll have the same problem. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mapping your model properties with the Fluent API?

[Configuring Relationships with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620)

[Configuring/Mapping Properties and Types with the Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617)

I had the same problem. My `Donation` entity has a navigation property to another entity called `PaymentTransaction`, which is required so is set as foreign key.

```
public class DonationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Donation>{
    public DonationMap() {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.FirstName).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.LastName).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.DonationAmount).HasColumnType("Money").IsRequired();

        // Column Mappings

        // PaymentTransaction is a navigation property
        //HasRequired(m => m.PaymentTransaction); // gives me column name "PaymentTransaction_PaymentTransactionId"
        HasRequired(m => m.PaymentTransaction).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("PaymentTransactionId"));

        // Table Mapping
        ToTable("Donation");
    }
}
```

Column name before specifically setting it with fluent mapping:

[image]

Column name after specifically setting it with fluent mapping:

[image]

Comment: I didn't, specially because it seems very simple to plug one more API for this (considering it's an ongoing project, also). But thank you anyway.

Comment: @Cesar Well if you want to stop `User` getting renamed to `User_UserId` using the code/model first approach then I don't see any other way other than using Fluent API or table migrations. I had the same problem and it worked for me, see updated answer above.

Comment: Thank you for the very complete examples, I'll try to check it tomorrow!